# Trouble getting numbers off of a webpage using re and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-re

i'm doing an assignement where i have to look throught a webpage, and pull out the numbers and compute the sum, however i'm having trouble getting the numbers and i believe my re isn't doing the job, here's the code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_687617.html'
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

tags = (soup.find_all('tr'))

numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', tags)

print (numbers)
```

e: #changed 'tags'to tags but the problem persists.

Comment: Can you please show the output and what was your expected output?

Comment: hello, the output i get is an empty list, my expected output would be a list containing the numbers. numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.findall()` expects a `string` as second argument. You are passing `'tags'` which will be passed as a string not a variable because of the quotes. And, this string doesn't has any numbers in it. So, the output is an empty list.

To get the right output, you can concatenate all the tags in one string and pass it to the function. Here's one approach:

```py
...

tags = (soup.find_all('tr'))

# Concatenate all tags to one string
string = ""
for tag in tags:
  string += str(tag)

numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', string)
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
['97', '96', '94', '91', '90', '86', '84', '81', '81', '77', '76', '75', '75', '74', '72', '70', '70', '70', '66', '64', '64', '63', '56', '52', '52', '47', '47', '44', '43', '40', '40', '40', '40', '37', '36', '35', '33', '31', '30', '28', '22', '21', '21', '11', '11', '10', '7', '6', '2', '1']
```

### Edit

A simpler way without using regular expression:

```py
tags = soup.find_all('span', class_="comments")
numbers = [tag.get_text() for tag in tags]
print(numbers)
```

Comment: Wow that was super helpful thank you very much, i can see now why i was wrong, what do you think would be a more pythonic way to go about this problem?

Comment: You can simply do it without using `re` which is a cleaner way. I have edited the answer with that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the variable `tags`, not the string 'tags':
Your line

```
numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', 'tags')
```

should be

```
numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', tags)
```

Comment: Hi i did that but i'm still getting an empty list in return.